# Powering a Fan with Raspberry Pi

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi

I have a 12V computer fan that I want to hook up to my Raspberry Pi. It has a 7V sensor, 12V power and ground. I know that the Pi can only supply 5v so I’m just wondering how to hook it up to the Pi and be able to control the fan through GPIO pins.

I do have a 12V Power supply

Comment: If it's a 12 V fan, and you only have 5 V available you're out of luck.  Get a boost converter to generate the 12 V for you, and switch the fan with a mosfet.

Comment: You can use a PNP/NPN transistor pair to switch 12V with 5V

Comment: @TomHeeley thanks for clarifying the power supply! Means I can keep my answer as it is! Lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to switch 12V with 5V, then you can use a PNP/NPN pair of transistors. A circuit I have used before:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTEMse.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you apply 5V to the base of Q2, Q1 will allow the 12V to pass. I left the part numbers as the generic ones in the schematic editor so you will have to make sure you get ones that can handle the current requirements etc.

There are plenty of PNP/NPN switching circuits online you can google if you want a more in depth look or if you want to do something a bit more sophisticated, but this should give you a starting point.

Pretty sure there is a name for this configuration but I can't remember it! If anyone does, feel free to add it in!

Comment: I read the question as though there is only a 5 V supply available. This is a good answer though, if there's a 12 V supply present +1

Comment: @Colin__s Oh yes I see.... I read it as he has a 12V supply and GND for the fan but the Pi can only supply 5V as a signal...  Now I am unsure lol

Comment: Why a pair? In this application a single NPN transistor or an nMOS is perfectly fine (you don't need to switch the high side in this kind of application)

Comment: @frarugi87 I put this forward as it is a circuit I have used before so in my eyes it is a tried and tested way of switching 12V on and off with 5V. I haven't seen a single NMOS that could do it with such a difference in voltage though, although I have never looked for one. Basically, I have used this a number of times, and it works, hence I put it forward as an answer.

Comment: If you have a simpler way of doing it, by all means write your own answer. Always good to have a range of choices, then the OP can make a decision on what would suit his application best

Comment: What's wrong with a single NPN with an appropriate base resistor?

Comment: @ScottSeidman nothing is wrong with it..... not sure where you got that from! Read the comments above as to why my answer contains the circuit I suggested

Comment: I'm a huge fan of this answer

Comment: Let me rephrase. Why is this better than a single npn transistor?

Comment: @ScottSeidman  Erm... could you please quote the part where I insinuated that this is better than a single NPN? Because I'm unsure why you seem to think I said that :/

Comment: You inferred that this was more "sophisticated" than a one transistor solution.  I'm just wondering why.  Would a 5 transistor solution be even more sophisticated?  When you skip over the obvious answer, rigor suggests that you tell us why.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I think you may need to re-read that part. I didn't mean it was more sophisticated than a single NPN. That hadn't even been mentioned when I posted the answer. In fact, as you can see I encouraged someone else to post it. I meant the OP could Google the NPN/PNP switching circuits to find a more sophisticated or better version than the one I posted. I also stated this was a starting point. At no point did I say this was better or more sophisticated. And read the comments again, I said why I posted this circuit already

Comment: @ScottSeidman I can re-word it if you like? I personally can't see how you came to that conclusion but if you tell me which part I inferred this is a more sophisticated solution, I will be happy to edit it and rephrase

Comment: @ScottSeidman if I have managed to clear up your confusion, could you let me know or remove your comments? If not, could you explain a bit more as to how you came to your conclusion?

Answer (score 8):

There are circuits where switching the high side of the load is necessary (for instance, when your load has a communication interface, or when you are reading back something from the load like the current).

In this case, however, you don't need any of these features. So I recommend a single transistor solution (cheaper):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f40kSU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit is fine if the current in the fan is up to let's say 50mA.

If the current is higher, you'll need to either use a "two stages transistor" (aka darlington) or use a power transistor which can handle more current (and in order to provide it the required base current you'll need a smaller transistor):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRfjK5.png)</sup>

In the first case you can choose any darlington (I found the 2N6426); in the second the PNP should be one which can handle the required current.

You can also use a single nMOS:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4y139.png)</sup>

In this case, you will have to choose a MOS transistor with a low Vgs-th; for instance the VN2222 or the 2N7000 can handle some hundreds of mA.

Final note: since the load can have inductive behaviors, please remember to add a freewheeling diode

Comment: Nice solution! And well explained too. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a simpler way of doing it, by all means write your own answer. Always good to have a range of choices, then the OP can make a decision on what would suit his application best

ok @MCG
I'm not the best drawer of schematics with these programs,but here it is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwxt8x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The high gain of the tip122 Darlington transistor with internal dampening diode makes a low parts count solution for driving everything from lamps to solenoid coils. The 120 ohm resistor is the minimum resistance needed for total switch operation, but you can increase this resistance if you need a bias range for varying the speed. depending on the gpio current capacity, you might need to increase this resistance.

Comment: I think this may need an explanation to go with it. @frarugi provided a good one with his answer.

Comment: ok, I'll add an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a single npn transistor. Q1 should be rated to handle the current drawn by the fan. D1 protects Q1 against voltage spikes when the fan is turned off. Q1 should be rated for V2 (~12V) + 0.7 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsAOux.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>